# PropertyAccessor.GetProperty( PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN) fails for outlook attachment

Tags: c#, email, outlook-addin

I need to create an OutLook add-in that catches emails with large attachments and replaces the attachment with a  URL that can be used to download the attachment.

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh290849.aspx) which shows how to modify an attachment before sending it that looked like a good starting point but the problem is that the call:

> const string PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN =
>                   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";
>
> var attachmentData =
>                       attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(
>                       PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN);

fails with an error saying the property is unknown or cannot be found.

I can call attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty() to get the attachment type which is 1 (ATTACH_BY_VALUE) so I should be able to get the data with attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN)

I am wondering if there is a privilege problem here. I see here: dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions  that there are Outlook add-in permissions and that if I did not ReadWriteItem access then this could fail. I do not know how or where this is set though. They mention about it being set in the manifest but I do not see where I can do that.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015.

Answer (score 3):

Outlook Object Model cannot retrieve large binary or string MAPI properties using `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. On the low level (Extended MAPI, C++ or Delphi only), `IMAPIProp::GetProps()` does not work for the large `PT_STING8 / PT_UNICODE / PT_BINARY` properties. They must be opened as `IStream` (`IMAPIProp::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN, IIS_IStream, ...))`. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, its attachment objects expose `AsText`, `AsArray`, `AsStream`, etc properties.

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set item = Session.GetMessageFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)
for each attach in item.Attachments
    MsgBox attach.AsText
next
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but at this point I think my problem is more basic. In my test the attachment was a small text file so I think I should be able to get it PropertyAccessor.GetProperty() although in the end I will need to use something else because of the size limitation.

If I sue attachment.SaveAsFile() I also get an exception telling me I do not have appropriate permission to perform this operation.

MSVS and C# is not my native development environment and so I suspect there is something very basic  I am missing.

Comment: What is the value of the Attachment.Type property? Take a look at the message with OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/)? Select the message, click IMessage button, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab, double click on the attachment entry. Do you see the PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN property?

Comment: The PR_ATTACH_TYPE = 7 and there is a  PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN property.

Comment: PR_ATTACH_TYPE = 7 is the new ATTACH_BY_WEB_REF, which is for the new OneDrive web attachments. Are you sure PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN is present and you can see its value? When you save an attachment like that in Outlook 2016, it creates a *.url file pointing to a location from PR_ATTACH_LONG_PATHNAME_W.

Comment: PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN  is there and it contains the content of the attached file. There is no  PR_ATTACH_LONG_PATHNAME_W though.

Comment: Does the script above work if you install Redemption?

Comment: From inside the 'send' event handler where should I get the EntryID,  ActiveExplorer seems to be not valid from this context. The EntryID in Outlook.MailItem is nil.

Comment: Why do you need the entry id? Did you call MailItem.Save?

Comment: I am trying to get the example shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh290849.aspx to work.  The code is called when the mail is sent. I do not call 'save' any where. I wanted the entry id because that appears to be what you were getting in this statement: item = Session.GetMessageFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID).

Comment: If I add a mailItem.save() then it works! Well that only took me a few days. :(

Comment: The example used the currently selected item as a test. If you already have an Outlook item, you can replace Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID with YouMailItem.Entry. Or you can use GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject and pass your mail item. You will still need to call MailItem.Save if the item is unsaved.